# Json dynamic string list

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to return a list of validation errors from my mvc app to the client side to I can take use of the [jquery validation showError](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors)s which takes an object

I can get a list of fields and the the erorr(s) that apply to them in any way that is best suited.

I have tried a few formats already, dictionary and none of these serialise to the correct structure as required by the validation library.

ie.

```
{"fieldname":"some error for fieldname", "fieldname2": "some error for fieldname2"}
```

All of my examples seem to serialise into something along the lines of

```
{"Key": "fieldname", "Value" : "some error for fieldname"}
```

What is the best way to return my data and how can I get it serialised in the correct way that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (it is default JSON serializer for ASP.NET MVC 4 as well) and its `JsonWriter`:

```
StringWriter errorsStringWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter errorsJsonWriter = new JsonWriter(jsonStringWriter);
errorsJsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
errorsJsonWriter.WritePropertyName("fieldname"); 
errorsJsonWriter.WriteValue("some error for fieldname");
errorsJsonWriter.WritePropertyName("fieldname2"); 
errorsJsonWriter.WriteValue("some error for fieldname2");
...
errorsJsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
errorsJsonWriter.Flush();
```

You can return JSON generated this way with `ContentResult`:

```
return Content(errorsStringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString(), "application/json");
```

**UPDATE**

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) also supports dynamic JSON through `JObject`. In that case your code can look like this:

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.Add("fieldname", "some error for fieldname");
jsonObject.Add("fieldname2", "some error for fieldname2");
...
```

Creating `ContentResult` in this case can look like this:

```
    return Content(jsonObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None), "application/json");
```

Comment: this looks very promising will have to try it out

Comment: hmm using the json object just returns [[]]

Comment: @DanielPowell You mean the `return Json(jsonObject);` approach?

Comment: yeah, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562734/mvc-return-jsonarray-as-json

Comment: @DanielPowell I can't retest it until later today, at this point I can only suggest catsing to `dynamic` before adding objects to JArray: `jsonArray.Add(json as dynamic);`. Please check that and let me know if this helps.

Comment: returning it as the contentresult works correctly, ill try dynamic

Comment: dynamic just resulted in having a [[[[]]],[[[]]],[[[]]],[[[]]]]

Comment: @DanielPowell Ok I checked the source code of ASP.NET MVC 4 and it seems I'm a victim of trusting in headlines. ASP.NET MVC 4 is still JavaScriptSerializer. In that case it will not work without dedicated `ActionResult`. You can find one here: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx. Sorry for the mistake.